# Why does the file name needs to be repeated?

Tags: linux, bash, puppet, augeas

If I do

```
augtool --noautoload --transform "sshd incl /etc/ssh/sshd_config" ls "/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/"
```

then I get the tree structure of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but here I have written the file path twice, where the last time it is prefixed with `/files`.

**Question**

Would it be possible to do the same, but only specify the file path ones?

Comment: You haven't repeated the same path at all. The first path is /etc/ssh/sshd_config which seems to be a file, and the other is /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/ which seems to be a directory (based on the trailing slash.)

Comment: `cfgFile=/etc/ssh/sshd_config;augtool... incl $cfgfile ls /files/$cfgFile/` is about as good as you can do. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Augeas loads all the files it knows about, which can be quite slow.

To prevent this, your command uses `--noautoload` which bypasses automatically loading files from lenses. While this makes Augeas much faster, it also means it doesn't know about `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` anymore, so you need to map this file to the `Sshd.lns` lens manually again, which is done with `--transform Sshd.lns incl /etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Here is another possibility (from [augeas-sandbox](https://github.com/raphink/augeas-sandbox/blob/master/augloadone)) to load any file known to Augeas and bypass other lenses:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE=$1

if [ -z "$FILE" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <FILE>"
  exit 1
fi

augtool -L -i <<EOF
rm /augeas/load/*["$FILE"!~glob(incl) or "$FILE"=~glob(excl)]
load
set /augeas/context /files$FILE
EOF
```

This script will use autoload statements so you don't have to specify which lens to use, but it will only load the lens you want for your file, making Augeas faster. Additionally, it sets `/augeas/context`, so you can use relative paths:

```
$ augloadone /etc/ssh/sshd_config
rm : /augeas/load/*["/etc/ssh/sshd_config"!~glob(incl) or "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"=~glob(excl)] 1158
augtool> ls .
```